# pytest gives error after installing pytest-ordering module

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I'm trying to learn pytest and have a very simple code without using fixtures to begin with:

```
import pytest

def test_methodA():
    print ("hello")
```

In the terminal when i execute -

```
py.test -v -s.
```

It works fine but after installing `pytest-ordering` it gives a error saying:

```
"AttributeError: 'Function' object has no attribute 'get_closest_marker'"
```

Is it mandatory to use the features of `pytest-ordering` after the module is installed? i don't have even have an import statement for it.

Comment: Looks like the plugin is not compliant with changes in pytest 4.0; downgrade pytest: `pip install --upgrade "pytest<4" `.

Comment: i'm using pytest version  - 3.3.2 and pytest-ordering is 0.6

Comment: Then update pytest to at least 3.6, as the function was introduced in that version first.